# Calling jQuery Ajax inside other function

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a problem with Ajax. I am modifying a game guiding me on other.

I have the function `gameOver` working fine in my guide game:

```
// Some variables

$(document).ready(function()
{

    ...

});

...

// Some functions

...

function gameOver() {

    ...

    post="points="+score+"&idapp=1";
    alert("IN");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "saveScore1.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: post,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data.msg);
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(xhr.status);
        }
    });
    alert("OUT");

}
```

But in the game I'm modifying the fragment of the `gameOver` function I'll show next is not working. It's not calling the `saveScore2.php` file and I don't know why. It's practically the same content code of the `$.ajax` function.

```
var game = {

    ...

    // Some variables and functions

    ...

    gameOver: function() {

        ...

        post="points="+score+"&idapp=2";
        alert("IN");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "saveScore2.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: post,
            success: function(data){
                alert(data.msg);
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(xhr.status);
            }
        });
        alert("OUT");
    }

};

$(window).load(function() {

    ...

}
```

I will be very grateful for the help I can get to solve this problem.

CLARIFICATION:

The `IN` and `OUT` alerts are showed in the first game. The `IN` alert is showed in the second game but the `OUT` alert it doesn't show in the second game. Ignore the success and error alerts inside the `$.ajax` function in both games. They are never showed in the first game or in the second game.

Comment: the code you posted so far doesn't seem to have any issues, however when it's in a var you should call the function as game.gameOver instead of just gameOver... see where you register your event.

Comment: The method gameOver it's calling correctly. I put an alert just before the $.ajax function and the alert was showed. The problem is in the $.ajax =(

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion it's not calling saveScore2.php? Describe your procedure, maybe it's calling it but you have a redirect set on your server or your server uses linux and saved the file with a different capitalization (linux file names are case sensitive).

Comment: I print an alert with php inside saveScore.php in the first game and the alert was showed. In the second game i do the same thing and the alert doesn't show. =(

Comment: Check in the browser, use your browser's specific developer tools and check the net[work] tab, I'm sure the request is going through but the server responds with an error or something that's otherwise not suitable to call your success function.

Comment: I made a clarification of the question :)

Comment: If you're not willing to check the developer tools I'm not willing to waste any more time on this.

Comment: I'll check the network tab. It doesn't seen to be problems. What in specific i have to check there? Thanks in advance

Comment: If when doing whatever triggers the second function the request is done and what happens with the request, what does the server respond to it.

Comment: As @xception said, you have to check the developer tools. My guess is there is an error on the server side (you are using a different url, **saveScore2.php** vs **saveScore1.php**). Do you know what you are looking at on the **Network** tab? I highly suggest having the developer tools open when you load the website; that will capture all of the requests. Then skim down the line & see where the call to **saveScore2.php** is made. Click the **saveScore2.php** request to see if it has a **200 OK** code. If it doesn't have a **200 OK** code then you need to investigate. Check the **Console** tab.

Comment: Thank you very much @JoeFletch and xception. I will look at this and I will put here what I found. :)

Comment: @JoeFletch I alredy check the Network Tools and in the first game, saveScore1.php appeared in the list but in the second game saveScore2.php doesn't appeared in the list. I think the problem is in the javascript codes I put here in the question. That javascript codes make the calls to those php files. :(

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are setting the object variable `game` with a method of `gameOver`. So somewhere in your code you need to call `game.gameOver` to call the function.

Comment: The method gameOver it's calling correctly. I put an alert just before the $.ajax function and the alert was showed. The problem is in the $.ajax =(

Comment: Ok. I would use Chrome / Firebug to see if there is a call listed in the **Network** tab (press F12 in Chrome to get there). There maybe a problem on the server side. Check it out and let me know what you see.

Comment: I do what you told me. It' doesn't seems to be a problem in the server. But i'm not sure. Note that the code inside gameOver is practically the same in the "correct game" and in the "problem game". I put an alert in the "correct game" before the $.ajax function and next to this function and worked fine. In the "problem game" i put an alert before the $.ajax function and worked fine, but the alert next to this function it doesn't showed.

Comment: Do you mean that the alert inside of the `success` and `error` methods are not firing?

Comment: In addition, when checking the **Network** tab in Firebug/Chrome, what is the response from the server? Is anything highlighted in **red**? If so, then please report back.

Comment: No, i mean other alerts. This.
alert("Hello");
$.ajax({
...
});
alert("Bye");
Both are showed in the first game. But in the second game only the first is showed.

Comment: I am not following you. At this point, I suggest that you update your question to be more clear, highlighting **EXACTLY** which lines are not firing in your code.

Comment: Done, i made the clarification :)